# How to find the time for a treatment when counting the difference of pills taken?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, word-problem, discrete-time

The problem is as follows:

> Louis took three and a half type $A$ pills every twelve hours and a
> half type $B$ pills every $6$ hours. He did this until the difference
> in the number of pills taken was $25$. If he starts taking both types
> of pills together, how long does the treatment last and how many pills
> had he taken in total?.

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{4.75 days and 44 pills}\\
2.&\textrm{4.75 days and 45 pills}\\
3.&\textrm{3.75 days and 43 pills}\\
4.&\textrm{4.5 days and 45 pills}\\
\end{array}$

How exactly should I solve this problem?.

What I've attempted so far was to use this formula which is based on the fact that the number of pills taken can be found by computing the division of the total time with that of the interval between each dose plus $1$ which guarantees to account all together and without falling in the off by one error.

Thus the labels are as follows:

$t_{1}$: total elapsed time

$t_{2}$: interval time between dose

$\textrm{total of A pills: a}$

$\textrm{total of B pills: b}$

$\left(3+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{t_1}{t_2}+1\right)=a$

$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{t_1}{t_2}+1\right)=b$

$a-b=25$

Replacing with the given information:

$\left(3+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{t_1}{12}+1\right)=a$

$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{t_1}{6}+1\right)=b$

$\left(3+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{t_1}{12}+1\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{t_1}{6}+1\right)=25$

Then solving this yields:

$t=\frac{528}{5}$

But this number is not an integer and it doesn't seem to help me to get the requested time. Thus I need help in the right approach for this question. Can someone help me here? It would help me a lot a wordy answer so I can understand what is going on.

Comment: @user10354138 Yes, they replaced them with different numbers once they got into the algebra.

Comment: If the difference in the numbers of pills is odd the sum of the number of pills is also odd, so choice $1$ cannot be right.

Answer (score 1):

In the time interval $[0,12)$ he takes $3\frac 12\ A$ pills and $1\ B$ pill because the half $B$s are taken every six hours.  That means the $A$ pills pull ahead by $2\frac 12$ pills every $12$ hours.  It takes $10$ of those $12$ hour intervals to have $A$ ahead by $25$, but no pills have been taken for the last $6$ hours.  The first time $A$ was exactly $25$ ahead was $6$ hours before, which is after $4.75$ days.  The $A$ pills were taken at $0,0.5,1,1.5\ldots 4.5$ days, which is $10$ times and $35$ pills.  The $B$ pills were taken at $0,0.25,0.5,0.75\ldots 4.75$ days, which is $20$ times and $10$ pills.

Comment: Yes, if we count the time at $120h$ both types will be taken again and $A$ will exceed $B$ by $28$ and never look back.  That is why the question was careful to specify that both pills were taken at time $0$ and why my interval was open at the $12h$ point.

Comment: I guess **If we don't count the last time point $t=120\,h$ the synchronization between the two will not occur** hence $B$ pills will had been taken $6$ hours before. I don't know if this is what you had in mind. Can you please attend these doubts?.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, what I meant to say was as follows, I'm still confused. I mean in $12$ hours he should have taken $2\times 3\frac{1}{2}$ $A$ pills and three times $\frac{1}{2}$. But you are accounting for the intervals. I don't know why. Assuming that **we do not count the pills taken exactly on $t=12\,h$** it only then makes sense what you said. The next part of your answer I'm stuck.

Comment: Continued I mean yes $10$ times of those intervals will make $A$ ahead from $B$ by $25$ pills. But I don't know why you say that $A$ was ahead $6$ hours before?. Did this results from not counting the last time point?.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my comments and you had answered thus, what I meant to say about my question is **why** are we not counting the last $t=120\,h$ time interval. To my intuition it seems that it was along with what you mentioned. I do think that you might want to add this as part of your answer because this helped to clear my doubt.

Comment: Please do not delete a comment I have responded to, as it makes the response not make sense to people who come after.  I never talked of synchronization.  The longer you go, the more $A$ exceeds $B$, but there is a step back at $12k+6$ hours when you take $\frac 12\ B$ and no $A$.  At $108$ hours $A$ is ahead by $25\frac 12$, but at $114$ hours the lead drops back to $25$.  I suggest you make a spreadsheet with one line for each $6$ hour increment, columns for the number of $A$ and $B$ pills taken at each time, the total number of $A$ and $B$ pills taken so far, and the difference.

Comment: I was making clear that we were counting the pills just before those taken at $120$ hours.  That was convenient.  Then I said we needed to go back to the last time pills were taken.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. So every $12$ hours, he takes $3.5A + B$ pills. In $24$ hours, he takes $7A + 2B$ pills, for a difference of $5$ pills. That suggests $5$ days, but now we can look at that last $24$ hours.

After $4$ days, he's taken $28A + 8B$ pills. Oh, but this is one of those tricky ones, isn't it? His first set of pills was at $t = 0$, which means he's taken these $28A + 8B$ pills at $t = 3.5$ (measuring $t$ in days). Then at $t=3.75, P = 28A + 8.5B$. At $t = 4, P = 31.5A + 9B$. At $t=4.5, P = 35A + 10B$.

$4.5$ days and $45$ pills seems to be choice number 4. I think algebra just... isn't actually the best way to solve this, partly because these are stepwise functions. But for an algebraic solution, I'd probably use rates so I don't have an "elapsed time" as well as two "interval times." So measuring $t$ in hours,

$$A = 3.5 + \frac{3.5}{12} t$$
$$B = 0.5 + \frac{0.5}{6} t$$
$$A-B = 25 = 3.5 + \frac{3.5}{12} t - 0.5 - \frac{0.5}{6} t$$

And that also yields an answer of $4.4$ days, which is what you had. So then you have to look at where the stepwise function is at $4.25$ and $4.5$ days, and $4.5$ wins as above.

Comment: Yay your answer is very conversational and I like that a lot!. Yes it was much clearer that you explained it this way because **we can see what is happening that final 4th day.** I'm not very savvy with step-wise functions. I do remember a bit from my classes years ago. Therefore I require that you explain the last part of your answer because $4.4$ days. **How does it become into $4.5$?.**

Comment: Becuse is stepwise function, it will be to floor, then is $4.5$ just because is closer to that? But **how do I know the floor is at $4.5$? Maybe if you explain this better I could understand what you had just said.